# Elm package source code

Tags: elm

I'd like to see the source code of elm-lang/core that is in use in my project.

My project has:

```
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
```

Right now elm compiler says

```
Cannot find variable `Json.Decode.Decoder`.
`Json.Decode` does not expose `Decoder`.
```

From [github source](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Json/Decode.elm) I can see that it's exposing `Decoder`. Would like to see if I have the wrong version of Elm or something.

Just in case - my elm-package.json has

```
"dependencies": {...
    "elm-lang/core": "5.1.1 <= v < 6.0.0",
     ...
},
"elm-version": "0.18.0 <= v < 0.19.0"
```

Comment: Packages are downloaded to the `elm-stuff` directory in your project root. You should be able to see source there.

Comment: Thanks! And I see the same source as I see in the github, don't understand the error.. hmm

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but you could try deleting `elm-stuff` and recompiling. I've had occasional mysterious errors that were fixed by that nuclear option

Comment: Seems like I'm just reading Elm wrong.. will try to thinker with it some more

Comment: Can you post the source code where you're actually trying to use `Json.Decode.Decoder`? If you are using it incorrectly, this compiler message may be legitimate.

Comment: `img [ src model.gifUrl, on "load" (Decode.Decoder (toString model.gifUrl) ] []`

Comment: Ok, yea, that's a compile error. I've added an answer that should address things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example use in the comments shows that you are using `Decoder` like this:

```elm
on "load" (Decode.Decoder (toString model.gifUrl)
```

That is indeed a compiler error. While the `Json.Decode` package exposes a `Decoder` *type*, it does not expose a `Decoder` *constructor*. This is known as an opaque type, meaning you can't construct a `Decoder` value yourself, but only by using functions from the `Json.Decode` package. Opaque types can be exposed by having a module defined like this:

```elm
module Foo exposing (MyOpaqueType)
```

You can specify which constructors are exposed in one of the following ways:

```elm
-- only exposes Constructor1 and Constructor2
module Foo exposing (MyType(Constructor1, Constructor2))

-- exposes all constructors of MyType
module Foo exposing (MyType(..))
```

By your example code, I am inferring that you want some `Msg` to occur when an image is fully loaded. If that were the case, then you could use something like this:

```elm
type Msg
    = ...
    | ImageLoaded String

viewImage model =
    img [ src model.gifUrl, on "load" (Json.Decode.succeed (ImageLoaded model.gifUrl)) ] []
```

[Here is an example of how to handle both the image `load` and `error` events](https://ellie-app.com/3RdMy3Nk7n7a1/0).